# Libgdx app can't run on android emulator

Tags: android, libgdx, android-virtual-device

I've been trying to figure this out for couple days. I've tried to run the app on android emulator on eclipse and when I clicked on my app it gives me an error "unfortunately, app has stopped" The following is the Logcat.

```
03-21 19:01:19.145: I/AndroidGraphics(863): Managed buffers/app: { }
03-21 19:01:19.585: W/dalvikvm(863): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 87
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863): com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/texture.png
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:142)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:133)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:112)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:104)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.AukaD.myHelpers.AssetLoader.load(AssetLoader.java:33)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.AukaD.FlyBird.MyGame.create(MyGame.java:10)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:334)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: data/texture.png (Internal)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:74)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.length(FileHandle.java:563)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.length(AndroidFileHandle.java:162)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:218)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  ... 10 more
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data/texture.png
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:72)
03-21 19:01:19.715: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  ... 14 more
```

Comment: We would need code, but the error says it can't load data/texture.png.  You should probably make sure that everything is correct with loading it.  You should also probably make sure the size is something that can be handled.

Comment: What happens if you run the desktop version?

Comment: Does this `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data/texture.png` tell you anything?

Comment: @donfuxx It works fine on desktop version, runs smoothly.

Comment: the texture.png is inside your android project or in the desktop project?

Comment: Hey Thx! everyone for helping, I figured it out. I saved the texture.png in assets folder as capital "Texture.png, but tried to load it as "texture.png". Saved my life.

Answer (score 2):

To not leave this question unanswered...

It runs on your desktop version, because your desktop version is Micosoft Windows and they do not care about the case in file names. `data/Texture.png` is the same as `data/tEXtUre.png` for Windows and thus it works without any problems.

Every other OS that I know of, cares about the case in filenames and thus on Android you don't find the file when loading it as `data/texture.png` when it is actually named `data/Texture.png`.

I'd advise you to always use lower case only when it's about files.

Comment: Are you sure that windows is case insensitive? I am using Eclipse on windows 7 and as much as i remember (i am not sure...) i got some `couldn't load file` errors cause of the case. As i said those errors could also have been for something different (wrong name). So well i am just curious about that :P

Comment: @Springrbua I'm pretty sure. It also explains the behaviour which is described in the question here. It may depend on the Windows version though.

Comment: Ah okay thanks a lot, maybe it was another error in my case, i can't remember. Good to know

Comment: @noone was right! It solved my problem after switching capital "Texture" to small t.